# Concourse CI using 2 github domains

Tags: concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-git-resource, concourse-fly, concourse-resource-types

I would like how i can pass to my concourse pipeline two different github domains depending on the repository that is reading where is allocated in one or another as my pipeline reads several repositories.

Thank you